# Mobiscroll changeWheel Example?

Tags: jquery, html, mobiscroll

I'm using Mobiscroll and want to change the array of values in the second wheel depending on the value of the first wheel.

The documentation says changeWheel should handle this but no example of how to implement. Does anyone know the correct syntax for Mobiscroll inst.changeWheel?

Comment: Have you had a look at this answer?<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444081/changewheel-functionality-how-it-works> I don't believe you can change the values in the wheel but rather which value is selected.